# Website Needs Reload After Deleting A Document Firestore

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

After adding am onClick event on a button, I tried and the page needs to be reloaded before changes can be seen. I want to make the changes to be displayed immediately right after clicking the button. Below is the code I used in deleting a document from Firestore database.

```
<button onClick={() => {deleteAccount(account.id)}}>Cancel</button>
```

```
const deleteAccount = async (id) => {
    const userDoc = doc(db, 'accounts', id);
    await deleteDoc(userDoc);
  }
```

Comment: Please show also where you load the account list for display. The problem is you need to keep these items in react state and patch the react state when the delete is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a similar problem. One way I used to achieve this was to use a state. Place that inside of a useEffect hook as dependency.

Every time an account is deleted the effect would take place causing a re-render or somewhat of a refresh without actually doing a refresh yourself.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getAccount();
}, [change]);
```

Then place this inside another useEffect when the list changes